# How can I correctly format these loops in C how my professor wants it?

Tags: c

For my lab project I have to

> For each integer 0 < `n` <= 100, find all of the integers between one and `n` which divide `n` without a remainder.

I have worked out the code but I am unsure how to format it in the way he wants.

**Format:** `number(# of factors): factors`

**Examples:**

```
2:( 2) 1,2
3:( 2) 1,3
4:( 3) 1,2,4
```

**What the current output looks like:**

```
1: 1
2: 1
2: 2
3: 1
3: 3
4: 1
4: 2
4: 4
5: 1
5: 5
6: 1
6: 2
6: 3
6: 6
7: 1
7: 7
8: 1
8: 2
8: 4
8: 8
9: 1
9: 3
9: 9
10: 1
10: 2
10: 5
10: 10
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ini[100], i, j, d, n = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        n = n+1;
        ini[i] = n; 

        for (d = 1; d <= n; d++){
            if (ini[i] % d == 0)
                printf("%d: %d\n", ini[i], d);
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Put all the divisors in an array and increment a counter. Then print the counter followed by the array elements.

Answer (score 2):

Aw, c'mon, let's have a little fun here. Everyone else is suggesting the "usual" way. But Back In The Day (tm) we didn't have memory to waste on things like keeping track of stuff. We just used the paper as our memory! :-)

I suggest looping over the values to be tested (1 - 100), then inside the first loop have another loop which counts from from 1 to n, printing the divisor values which give a remainder of zero. At the end of the loop I'd overprint the `n` value and then add in the number of factors found, then loop back for the next value.

In code this looks a lot like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
  int n, d, i;
  int factor_count;

  for (n = 1 ; n <= 100 ; n += 1)
    {
    printf("%3d(   ): ", n);

    factor_count = 0;

    for (d = 1 ; d <= n ; d += 1)
      {
      if (n % d == 0)
        {
        printf("%c%d", (factor_count > 0 ? ',' : ' '), d);
        factor_count += 1;
        }
      }

    printf("\r%3d(%3d)\n", n, factor_count); 
    }
  }
```

This code takes advantage of the fact that `\r` returns the print carriage (or the cursor on video terminals) to the left margin without advancing the roller (or the cursor - really, the cursor is *far* too busy and needs a rest! :-) to the next line, in order to avoid having to keep an array to store the factors in. It would be a lot of fun to watch run on an old ASR-33 Teletype - anybody got one to test with?

:-)

Comment: I like it - not dissimilar to my solution, but more memory efficient and without introducing `sprintf()`.  However does rely on the terminal not translating a CR into a CR+LF (if I were being pedantic, but that is a thing).

Comment: Back-In-The-Day (tm), when ASR-33's roamed the earth, roaring (well, clattering... :-) wildly, this would not only have avoided having to remember the divisors which produced a remainder of zero - it would **also** have printed the values of `n` in **bold-face**! :-)

Comment: Suggest change list output to `printf( "%d,", d ) ;`, then change the print after then loop to `printf( "\b\r%3d(%3d)\n", n, factor_count ) ;`.  The backspace will delete the last comma _then_ return the carriage.  Tada!

Comment: @Clifford, did you test? I thought `\b` moves the caret but doesn't remove the character. `\b \r...` might work.

Comment: @LegendofPedro : Yes, deninitely add the space - good spot. https://onlinegdb.com/HyE_1QW3S

Answer (score 1):

Before adapting your solution to generate the desired output, it would help to see the wood for the trees by removing the redundancy from your current solution:

In this solution, `n == i` is invariant  so `n` is redundant, and the array `ini[]` is entirely redundant, because you only ever read/write `ini[i]` and `ini[i] == i` is invariant, so all instances of `n` and `ini[i]` can be replaced with `i`.  `j` is just unused.  Then neither `i` nor `d` are used before or after the loops they control, so can be localised by declaring them in the loop thus minimising the scope (just good practice).

Then your code reduces to the following equivalent:

```
int main() {
    for( int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        for( int d = 1; d <= i; d++){
            if (i % d == 0)
                printf("%d: %d\n", i, d);
        }    
    }    

    return 0 ;
}
```

Now to obtain the required output, you don't know the number of factors until you have determined the list of factors, so the solution is to generate the list first while counting, then print the output.

That can be done in a second loop printing an array of stored factors, or even a second loop that recalculates the factors a second time - but those answers have already been given. Instead you could directly generate the list string as you go, then append it to the number/count output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    for( int i = 1; i <= 100; i++ )
    {
        char factor_list_out[80] = "" ;
        int factor_count = 0 ;
        int factor_out_index = 0 ;

        for( int d = 1; d <= i; d++)
        {
            if( i % d == 0)
            {
                factor_count++ ;
                factor_out_index += sprintf( &factor_list_out[factor_out_index], "%d,", d ) ;
            }
        }

        factor_list_out[factor_out_index - 1] = 0 ; // remove trailing comma
        printf( "%3d:(%2d) %s\n", i, factor_count, factor_list_out ) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Output:

```
  1:( 1) 1
  2:( 2) 1,2
  3:( 2) 1,3
  4:( 3) 1,2,4
  5:( 2) 1,5
  6:( 4) 1,2,3,6
  7:( 2) 1,7
  8:( 4) 1,2,4,8
  9:( 3) 1,3,9
 10:( 4) 1,2,5,10
 11:( 2) 1,11
 12:( 6) 1,2,3,4,6,12
 13:( 2) 1,13
 14:( 4) 1,2,7,14
 15:( 4) 1,3,5,15
 16:( 5) 1,2,4,8,16
 17:( 2) 1,17
 18:( 6) 1,2,3,6,9,18
 19:( 2) 1,19
 20:( 6) 1,2,4,5,10,20
 21:( 4) 1,3,7,21
 22:( 4) 1,2,11,22
 23:( 2) 1,23
 24:( 8) 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24
 25:( 3) 1,5,25
 26:( 4) 1,2,13,26
 27:( 4) 1,3,9,27
 28:( 6) 1,2,4,7,14,28
 29:( 2) 1,29
 30:( 8) 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30
 31:( 2) 1,31
 32:( 6) 1,2,4,8,16,32
 33:( 4) 1,3,11,33
 34:( 4) 1,2,17,34
 35:( 4) 1,5,7,35
 36:( 9) 1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36
 37:( 2) 1,37
 38:( 4) 1,2,19,38
 39:( 4) 1,3,13,39
 40:( 8) 1,2,4,5,8,10,20,40
 41:( 2) 1,41
 42:( 8) 1,2,3,6,7,14,21,42
 43:( 2) 1,43
 44:( 6) 1,2,4,11,22,44
 45:( 6) 1,3,5,9,15,45
 46:( 4) 1,2,23,46
 47:( 2) 1,47
 48:(10) 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,48
 49:( 3) 1,7,49
 50:( 6) 1,2,5,10,25,50
 51:( 4) 1,3,17,51
 52:( 6) 1,2,4,13,26,52
 53:( 2) 1,53
 54:( 8) 1,2,3,6,9,18,27,54
 55:( 4) 1,5,11,55
 56:( 8) 1,2,4,7,8,14,28,56
 57:( 4) 1,3,19,57
 58:( 4) 1,2,29,58
 59:( 2) 1,59
 60:(12) 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60
 61:( 2) 1,61
 62:( 4) 1,2,31,62
 63:( 6) 1,3,7,9,21,63
 64:( 7) 1,2,4,8,16,32,64
 65:( 4) 1,5,13,65
 66:( 8) 1,2,3,6,11,22,33,66
 67:( 2) 1,67
 68:( 6) 1,2,4,17,34,68
 69:( 4) 1,3,23,69
 70:( 8) 1,2,5,7,10,14,35,70
 71:( 2) 1,71
 72:(12) 1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,18,24,36,72
 73:( 2) 1,73
 74:( 4) 1,2,37,74
 75:( 6) 1,3,5,15,25,75
 76:( 6) 1,2,4,19,38,76
 77:( 4) 1,7,11,77
 78:( 8) 1,2,3,6,13,26,39,78
 79:( 2) 1,79
 80:(10) 1,2,4,5,8,10,16,20,40,80
 81:( 5) 1,3,9,27,81
 82:( 4) 1,2,41,82
 83:( 2) 1,83
 84:(12) 1,2,3,4,6,7,12,14,21,28,42,84
 85:( 4) 1,5,17,85
 86:( 4) 1,2,43,86
 87:( 4) 1,3,29,87
 88:( 8) 1,2,4,8,11,22,44,88
 89:( 2) 1,89
 90:(12) 1,2,3,5,6,9,10,15,18,30,45,90
 91:( 4) 1,7,13,91
 92:( 6) 1,2,4,23,46,92
 93:( 4) 1,3,31,93
 94:( 4) 1,2,47,94
 95:( 4) 1,5,19,95
 96:(12) 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,32,48,96
 97:( 2) 1,97
 98:( 6) 1,2,7,14,49,98
 99:( 6) 1,3,9,11,33,99
100:( 9) 1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the requirement are to indicate the number of factors before listing them, you will need two passed - one for counting the factors, and one for printing the factors.

Also note that this implementation does not take advantage of the `ini` vector, which (since for every element ini[i] = i, so there is no need for many of the declared variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        // First Pass: Counting
        int count = 0;
        for (int d=1 ; d<=i ; d++) {
            if ( i%d == 0 ) count++ ;
        } ;
        printf("%d: (%d)", i, count) ;
        // Second pass: Printing
        for (int d=1 ; d<=i ; d++) {
            if ( i%d == 0 ) printf(" %d", d) ; ;
        } ;
        printf("\n") ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the divisors in an array. Then print the elements of the array in the format required. You can also count the number of divisors as you're finding them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        int divisors[100];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int d = 1; d <= i; d++){
            if (i % d == 0) {
                divisors[counter] = d;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d (%d): ", i, counter);
        for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
            printf("%s%d", (j == 0 ? "" : ","), divisors[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```